# Codeigniter sessions being inserted into database every random second (AJAX Application)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I'm working on a Codeigniter latest version 3.1.9.
I'm developing a mobile application and I use CI for API calls between client and server. However today I noticed there is a huge number of rows created in the sessions table. (I have chosen to store sessions in the database - Config file details below).
The funny part is there is only 5-6 developer tester accounts available and there are around 14,000+ sessions generated. I'm sure that is not at all normal and I'm missing something or the framework has issues with API calls.

I want my users to login once and never logout until they intentionally press the logout button so I have made the `sess_expiration` to a greater value. I'll also write the cookie config below. 
The login stay for unlimited time works, sessions storage and retrieval works but i'm now bothered about the huge rows generated in the sessions table.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'db_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 2307200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'system_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Wondering if I can create a PHP cron code and run it every day to delete any old sessions of a particular user by comparing it's timestamp. Or if there seems any better solution or fix, Please help.

**EDIT**
I use cloudflare protection. But I hope it has nothing to do here IMO.

**EDIT 2**
After intensive research, I checked the database values by downloading the blob files and it seems cloudflare is creating new IP address for every user that runs the app and as a result new row is generated with new IP addresses. So now I'm thinking if I remove the previous sessions rows of that user, will the session still work. Will Update.